# Error code: 0x80040E37 when import Excel files in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-connections

I am using SSIS 2008 (SQL 2008 R2), I am trying to import several Excel files (more than 100 files) into SQL Server using a FOREACH loop.  I can successfully do this for just only the first file. But when start the second file give me that huge amount of errors describe in black letters at the end. The excel files come with multiple sheets but I need just one sheet of each excel file. The Sheet label always come with the same `GSDR_XXXX_FACT$Query_from_WN7X64_XXXXX_XXXX_SG` where each of the sheet has `Data Connection`.

edit:I am using  this  [link]: [How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed)
WHERE INSTEAD OF use CSV Connection I replaced by "EXCEL Connection".
I leave empty the expression in the Excel connection... because if I tried to use "connection string" , or "excelfilepath" or "server name"... all them give error in the "excel source" from the DataFlowComponent"...

Any advice I really appreciated it.

```
[Excel Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.

SSIS package "GTO_pull_data_to_table_multiple_excel_A.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DF at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [576]: The final commit for the data insertion in "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" has started.
Information: 0x402090E0 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [576]: The final commit for the data insertion  in "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" has ended.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" wrote 35096 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DF at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [576]: The final commit for the data insertion in "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" has started.
Information: 0x402090E0 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [576]: The final commit for the data insertion  in "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" has ended.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "component "OLE DB Destination" (576)" wrote 35096 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.

******Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [1]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error: 0xC02020E8 at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [1]: Opening a rowset for "GSDR_XXXX_FACT$Query_from_WN7X64_XXXXX_XXXX_SG" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error: 0xC004706B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "component "Excel Source" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop Container: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (6) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at GTO_pull_data_to_table_multiple_excel_A: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (6) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "GTO_pull_data_to_table_multiple_excel_A.dtsx" finished: Failure**.
**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
```

Comment: If there is only ever 1 file in the folder, can you import each individual file? The fact that it fails validation makes me think one of the files has a bum format. SSIS requires exact metadata for importing data and unfortunately with Excel, it's been my experience that there's no good way to "fix" a busted source file-even if they look identical. You might also verify you have the same sheet name/named range.

Comment: By the moment if I run the dtsx for each file that I select in the excel source...works fine.. The issue is that does not pick up the next file in the loop