# SSIS package importing data from template instead of data file

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that has a ForEach loop

[image: ForEach loop]

This ForEach loop is set to look in a folder, e.g. \server\path\CompanyA\ for files of type *.txt, and to retrieve the Fully qualified file name[image]

The filename is saved into a User variable User::FileName
[image]

When the execution of the package reaches the Data Flow Task, it imports the data from the template file that is defined on the Connection Manager that I set up in order to get the metadata for the column mappings.
[image]

How can I get the package to import from the file that the ForEach loop found, instead of the template file?

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, as is often the case, while posting a question on here I find other interesting questions that I want to read later on, so I open them for reading later. Then, I found the answer on another (unrelated) question a few seconds after posting the question.

So, I found it on screenshot #15 of [How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed)

Thanks if you were looking into my question.