# Move a file that failed to import to a different folder in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I found this link that describes how to move a file after it has been imported using SSIS:

[How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed)

I would like to set up some error handling such that a file that fails to 100% successfully import gets moved into a different folder for manual review.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the same steps as in the question/answer you referenced, but change the destination if the import wasn't 100% successful.

Comment: That did it. I was able to add another link from the data flow task to a new file system task, change the link to "Failure" and create a new folder, adding one additional variable for the failures folder name.