# SSIS Script task storing DateTime in variable

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I'm not sure why this happens, but my script task is not storing a DateTime-Value in a variable.
This is the (till now) very basic code I've written:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        DateTime creationTime;
        DateTime modifiedTime;
        DateTime oldCreationDate = (DateTime)Dts.Variables["User::OldFileDate"].Value;
        DateTime oldModifiedTime = (DateTime)Dts.Variables["User::OldModifiedDate"].Value;

        Dts.Variables["User::OldFileDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
}
```

It's not done yet, but I wanted to check if the variable is stored or not. I checked the variables using the debugger, during runtime the varible changes, but if I look at the variable after the execution it is still the same value.
I also checked the properties and `ReadOnly` is `False` and the Variables are also added to the package.[image: Variables] [image: variable declaration in ssis] Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you not use an expression for this?  you could say `@[User::OldFileDate] = GETDATE() `

Comment: Hi R-Style, Is having this value as a variable necessary? What your trying to do can be achieved a WHOLE lot easier by just making a derived column called OldFileDate and set the value express to GETDATE()

Comment: Your code looks good.  In order to see the value of a variable during debug, you should set the breakpoint on the script task to post execute.  Run the whole package and not just the task and look in the locals window (that only shows during debug).  The variable value that you are showing in your screen shot is the design time value which will remain the same after debug.

Comment: Yes - variables in SSIS go back to their original value (design time value) after the package finishes regardless of what they are set to.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks, this is the info i needed... So it is not possible at all to store the changed variable after the package has finished?

Comment: Not unless you write it to a table or a text file or something. What are you actually trying to do? See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have .xls-File and I want to check if it's an updated one or not, if yes import it to the database, if not do nothing...

Comment: What do you mean by updated? Do you mean imported? A well proven pattern for this is: after import, move the file to a different folder (i.e. called _Imported_). Likewise, if the import fails, move it to a subfolder called _Failed_. Any attempt to remember the file name externally is just going to cause trouble. i.e. when the file naming convention changes

Comment: Or are you just trying to capture the last updated date of an existing file? You should get that from the file rather than storing it externally.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am going to implement your solution, that sounds actually lika a good pattern. Can you reference a link where a solution like yours is described? Thank you a lot!

Comment: This is pretty detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once stopped at a breakpoint, look at your variables in the watch window for run time values.  The variable window is not updated during debugging.

EDIT:  Based on your comment ignore the above.
You can save the variable at any time in your package including the end.  I suggest that you use an execute SQL task to:

```
Insert Into ImportedFiles (FileName, Imported) Values (?, getdate())
```

Based on comments to your question you want to determine if the file was imported previously.  You can do:

```
Select 1 From ImportedFiles Where FileName = ?
```

Then based on that query you can set up logic to either import the file or skip it.

Comment: I know that, I needed to know if it was possible to save the variable after the package is finished