# loading of the archive files into different folders with timestamps

Tags: sql, ssis

thank you in advance.

I am new to ssis and i need some help.
i have to create a package wherein, i have to a pick up dynamically changing  .csv files from different folders and load them to SQL table, after the files are loaded into the SQL table i need the files to be placed back into the folder they were picked up from.

i did a part of this by referring to this link: [How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/how-do-i-move-files-to-an-archive-folder-after-the-files-have-been-processed/6703691#6703691).

i was able to load all the files into one folder but i need to put back the files into different folders after they are loaded.
This is the File structure i have

D:\SAFI\2016_04||

file1.csv||

File2.csv||

File3.csv||

D:\SAFI\2016_05||

File1.csv||

File2.csv||

File3.csv||

I need the files to be loaded into the archive folder,but in the same manner.

exmaple:

D:\Archive\2016_04||

File1.csv||

File2.csv||

File3.csv||

D:\Archive\2016_05||

File1.csv||

File2.csv||

File3.csv||

it should create the folder itself and load the files accordingly.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry, how it is structured the flow? Move files and process them...if you put the files in the same location, why move them?

Comment: @ Alex:  I will be accessing the files from a remote server and i need to load the files and then move them into a local machine

Comment: What information do you have available? Are you using variables to store the file name / path? Are you using a loop?

Comment: I am using variables to store the information

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/57ge43ooj/

Comment: These are the variables i am using

Comment: Ok, use file system task to create the folder with date and then move file:`@[User::ArchiveFolder]+"\\"+(DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(getdate()) + "_"+  RIGHT(  "0" + (DT_WSTR,2) MONTH(getdate()), 2)`

Comment: @ alex : i appreciate your help, can you please elaborate on what steps i should do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use variables for folderpath, file name, directory name.
use execute SQL task

Answer (score 1):

use file system task with copy directory option

set  source connection and target connection using variable